# cannot connect with Bell modem

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an HP Pavillion Notebook with a Realtek RTL  8723BE 802.11bgn wireless adater. I recently switched isp provider for internet speed advertised at 1 Gbps.

The system worked fine for a few days but then the connection dropped. The problem was resolved temporarily but now I can no longer connect to my modem via wifi.

Diagnostics performed tell me that the driver is up to date and the device is working properly.

Any recommendatios?